# Cannot extends Model

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I want to create a `class` which extends `Model` :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query;

class ModelBase extends Model {

    var $table = null;

    public function __construct($table) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = $table;
    }
    ...
}
?>
```

This `class` ModelBase will be extended by all models `classes`.

At runtime I get an error saying : `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot override final method Phalcon\Mvc\Model::__construct() in D:\wamp\www\resto\app\models\ModelBase.php on line 117`

So how to extend correctly the Model `class` ?

Comment: You can extend `Model`: you can add new methods and properties; but you can only override those methods that aren't defined as `final` in `Model` - https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html

Comment: So how can I pass the `$table` variable into the class ModelBase ?

Comment: If you want to pass a table name to the constructor, you'll have to do it via the dependencyInjector

Comment: I am new to Phalcon , how can I do that ?

Comment: it is the name of the table associated to a class extending ModelBase.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *onConstruct* method in your base model.

```
class ModelBase extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    protected $_table;

    public function onConstruct()
    {
        $this->_table = 'whatever';
    }
}
```

You can then test that extending the base model works.

```
class SomeModel extends \ModelBase
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo $this->_table;
    }
}
```

So calling the extended model's test method will echo *whatever*

```
$model = new SomeModel();
$model->test();
```

Comment: how to pass a parameter to the `onConstruct` method to assign a value to the _table variable ?

Comment: @pheromix you can't because the parameters are hard coded (they are the di and model manager objects). plus you shouldn't have to since models are basically the records of a db table - you don't pass parameters to a db table - you set them directly with *$model->table = 'whatever'*. All other methods such as *setSource* are prepared for you so [check the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

If `$table` is the database table name for the model the best way to set it is:

```
class SomeModel extends ModelBase
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'table_name';
    }
}
```